# Proving $\left(1- \frac{x}{n+1}\right)^n > \frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{x^i}{i!}}$ for $x\in(0,1)$ (by induction?)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

> I'm trying to prove that for any $x \in (0,1)$, $$\left(1- \frac{x}{n+1}\right)^n > \frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{x^i}{i!}} \,\
> ,\,\,\,\text{for all $n$}$$

Proceeding by induction, the result is true when $n=1$ (by considering the product $(1- \frac{x}{2}) (1+x) >1$ ). Assuming the result is true when $n=k-1.$ When $n=k,$ $$ \left(1- \frac{x}{k+1}\right)^k\, \sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{x^i}{i!}$$
I'm stuck here as I'm not sure how to use the induction assumption for $k-1$.

-update-

It seems $\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^n$ is decreasing in $n$ (because $0<x<1$). Is there a way to use this fact to obtain the desired inequality?

Comment: I would expect a bit more work with the base case. It's not immediately obvious that inequality holds for all $x \in (0,1)$, and you want an airtight explanation. 

As for the inductive argument, your start seems fine. Proceed by shedding off a factor of $(1-\frac{x}{k+1})$ from the product and the kth term from the summation as well. Write up what you have after all of that, and then see how you might be able to use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @ChaoticGood  For the base case, once it is simplified , you're left with $1+x/2 - x^2/2$ which is greater than $1$ since $x^2 < x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, the opposite inequality (almost). By Taylor's formula
$$
\exp(x)= 1+x + \frac x2 \exp(c)
$$
with $c$ between $0$ and $x$. As a consequence,
$$
\exp u >  1+u
$$
for any $u\neq0$. Applying this result to $u=-\frac{x}{n+1}$ gives for any $x\in(0,n)$
$$
\exp\left(-\frac x{n+1}\right) >  1-\frac{x}{n+1} > 0,
$$
and
$$
\exp\left(-x\frac{n}{n+1}\right)>\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n}.
$$
Now,
$$
\exp\left(-x\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{\exp\left(x\frac{n}{n+1}\right)}=\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{xn}{n+1}\right)^k \frac{1}{k!}} < \frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{xn}{n+1}\right)^i \frac{1}{i!}},
$$
so
$$
\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n} < \frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{xn}{n+1}\right)^i \frac{1}{i!}}.
$$
Now the inequality you wanted. When $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
\frac{1}{\displaystyle 1+\frac x{n}} <  1-\frac x{n+1}.
$$
Indeed,
$$
\left(1+\frac xn \right)\left(1-\frac x{n+1} \right) = 1+\frac{x-x^2}{n(n+1)}>1.
$$
So
$$
\left(1-\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^{n} > \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}} $$
and we only need to show that
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} \leq \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^i}{i!}
$$
Now
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} =\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x^{i}}{i!} \frac{n!}{n^i(n-i)!},
$$
and
$$
\frac{n!}{n^i(n-i)!} = \frac{n(n-1)\ldots{(n-i+1)}}{n^i} <1
$$
so that's that.

Comment: Does this imply the above inequality (the one posted in the question) doesn't hold for all $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @Jane No it doesn"t that was just for fun. The proof is included now.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. About the reverse inequality, for any $x \in (0,1),\, \frac{xn}{n+1} \in (0,1)$. So, we have the reverse inequality for all $x \in (0,1)?$  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah never mind! In that case, what we have is $$(1- \frac{x}{n+1})^n < \frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x'\,^i}{i!} }$$, where $x' \in (0,1).$ In some sense, these are equal up to some constant (may be?).

Comment: @Jane every number is equal to another number up to a constant. The inverse inequality is just to highlight that as $n$ grows, this becomes quite a tight bound, since $n/(n+1)$ is close to one. In the limit, as you know, all of them tend to exp(-x), so this is expected.